# Generating a Line Graph using Seaborn or Matplotlib with: Year as hue, Month as X-Axis and Float Column as Y-Axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

The problem is I'm trying to generate a line graph using seaborn.lineplot() function, but I can't seem to find a way to generate a line graph like the one below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUKog.png

My dataset has the following columns: Year, Month, Day, Units, Price per Unit, Sales.
I've used the groupby function from pandas to sum the sales for each year in each month.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

years_list = [date.strftime('%Y/%#-m/%#-d') for date in pd.date_range('01/01/2000', '31/12/2019')]

data = {
    'year': [int(date.split('/')[0]) for date in years_list],
    'month': [int(date.split('/')[1]) for date in years_list],
    'day': [int(date.split('/')[2]) for date in years_list],
    'units': [np.random.randint(1,25) for turns in range(len(years_list))],
    'price_per_unit': [np.random.uniform(10, 100) for turns in range(len(years_list))]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['sales'] = df['price_per_unit'] * df['units']
each_month = df.groupby(['year', 'month'])['sales'].sum().reset_index()
```

Initially, I thought that using the code `sns.lineplot(x='month', y='sales', hue='year', data=each_month)` would automatically generate my desired graph, but it generated a confusing graph instead.

Anyone who has a solution for me? even if it isn't by using seaborn but matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that line indeed creates what you want. However, for numeric hue, `sns` automatically colors your line according to a continuous colormap. To overcome this, you can convert your `year` to string type:

```
each_month['year'] = 'Y' + each_month['year'].astype(str)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.lineplot(x='month', y='sales', hue='year', data=each_month)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set `month` as index and then groupby `year`, then just plot `sales`.

```py
each_month.set_index('month').groupby('year').sales.plot(legend=True, figsize=(10, 6))
```

[image]